# User does not exist when I logs in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to make my own site to log in django 1.7.
But when I get logs will be taken to a page to sign in and get a message that there is no such user. My user is in the database.

**VIEW**

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            print "User does not exist"
    return render_to_response('tests/login1.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" action="./" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `authenticate()` returns `None`. But you did not provide the code for it.

Comment: @KlausD. I know that it return None but why? It shuold be works.

Comment: Its possible that you are comparing the string password with the hashed version.. Have you verified the user exists? `User.objects.filter(username=username)` in a console?

Comment: @Sayse

`>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> a = User.objects.filter(username="test")
>>> print a
[<User: test>]
>>> `


Yes, this user exist

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) state that it will return None if it has an invalid password, have you tried authenticating in the console too with what you think the password is (and have you tried changing password)

Comment: Password is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending the `username` to the view because the `name` attribute is missing in your `input` tag. Instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
```

try this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
```